# Xcode Image Assets Catalog not able to see all images when Importing from Project?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am trying to use an Image Asset Catalog for our app. I create a new `Images.xcassets` folder successfully and I am able to add new files to it by dragging and dropping.

However, when I use the plus button in the lower left and select **Import from Project** only about 15 of the 100 images in our project show up. I can discern no apparent pattern between those that show up and those that don't. All of these assets are png files.

Any ideas on why some of the images don't show up?

Answer (score 1):

To import an asset in to the catalog, it must be a member of all the targets that the asset catalog is a member of.